# How to use material library for widget's import suggestions?

Tags: flutter, material-design

In my project when I create a new widget then AndroinStudio suggests me to import `cuppertino library` for the widget.

[image]

How to use `material library` for imports by default as my project is only Android project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some editors could suggest you to import that library, but to remove errors when creating a new Widget class, you should:

`import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';`

Answer (score 2):

> "as my project is only Android project"

What difference does that make?  You can use Material Design with every Flutter platform.

Comment: but we cann't use cupertino  with every Flutter platform, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, you can.  Apple doesn't care.  Flutter doesn't care.  Flutter is just painting on a canvas.  You control *every* pixel.